# How to access host files from VM oracle enterprise linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox, oracle-enterprise-linux

How to access host files from VM Oracle enterprise linux 6.3 (Virtual box).
It is not connected to internet and it has only terminal.
I downloaded **Winscp**, but it needs hostname(i.e IPaddress of VM), as it is not connected to internet, IP is not available. Is there any other alternative solution to access host files.

Comment: is it connected to a network of any kind?

Comment: yes @Takarii, it is connected to a LAN through ethernet.

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know which networking type you used for RHEL 6.3.

If you used NAT, then add port forwarding rule (host port 22 and guest port 22). and use IP address 127.0.0.1

If you used host-only  adapter the it will have private network IP address. Use that private IP address.

If you used bridged then it will have a public IP address.

Please refer my blog for further details:

ref: http://trainenv.blogspot.in/2016/03/virtual-networking.html